# Java console running in a screen autostart on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, java, screen, autostart, console

[Ubuntu 14.04 no desktop] I have a java console application, and I need to run all time (1st problem), as well as I can re-access the console whenever I want (2nd problem).

To solve the second problem, I use a screen, then run the jar file in it. So that I can re-attach the screen to access my console app.

I am now stuck with the 1st issue. I want to make the screen (along with the java app running inside) autostart with OS. Because I need the app running all time. Anyone give me an idea? I appreciate all your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make a start script for your java application.
Starting script: /usr/local/bin/myapp-start.sh
Make the script executable and place it in usr/local/bin and simply run it as any other application or add it to startp

example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar my_app.jar
```

To autostart you can add a line in .bash and make a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart/

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=command
Name=name
Comment=whatever 
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to re-attach my app whenever I want. Is there a way to do that without using screen?

Comment: Yes if you have a starting script placed where the OS searches for executable you can run it from terminal like any other application. By typing the script name in terminal my_script.sh just make sure it is executable.